# C++ nested for loops - inner product - marix multiplication

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested, inner-product

I have a matrix A with 4 rows and 3 columns and a matrix B with 8 rows and 4 columns. The coefficiants in the first column of B should denote those rows of A that I want to take for the inner product with the rows of B.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int ik, il, im;
//A Matrix
vector<vector<int>> A(4, vector<int>(3));
A={ {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1} };

//B Matrix
vector<vector<int>> B(8, vector<int>(4));
B={ {1, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 1, 0} ,{3, 0, 0, 1}, {4, 1, 0, 1}, {4, 0, 1, 1}, {4, 1, 1, 1} };

vector<int> BZI; 
BZI={{1},{2},{2},{2},{3},{4},{4},{4}};

//calculate inner products
vector<vector<int>> SKP_AB(4, vector<int>(8));
int skp_temp;
for(ik=0; ik<4; ik++)
{
  for(im=0; im<8; im++)
  {
    for(il=0; il<3; il++)
    {
    skp_temp=A[BZI[ik]][il]*B[im][il+1];
    SKP_AB[ik][im]+=skp_temp;
    }
  }
}
//Ausgabe von SKP_AB
cout << "\n" << "#SKP_AB" << "\n";
for(ik=0; ik<4; ++ik)
{
 for(il=0; il<8; ++il)
 {
 cout << setw(2) << SKP_AB[ik][il];
 }
cout << "\n";
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: I don't know where in the code the errors comes from. The output is not the wished inner products.

Comment: Is the comment section a place, where you should mention "I've got errors"?

Comment: @EisenMad Well, run your program in the debugger, step through line by line, and find out yourself.

Comment: I tried to debug it with the watches window in Code::Blocks but I did not find my error.

Comment: Have you given enough thought to what result you are actually trying to get?  I see there are 8 elements in `BZI` which matches the first column of `B`.  But you use a 0..3 index into it and never use the second half.  That feels like you haven't really thought through what you want it to accomplish.  But anyway, show us the output you got ans tell us why you think that output is incorrect.

Comment: Why is the line breaking not working? This is the output of my programm that is false:  <br/>
 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 2  <br/>
 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1  <br/>
 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1  <br/>
 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1  <br/>

Calculating by hand leads to this matrix:<br/>
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0   <br/>
 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0   <br/>
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  <br/>
 2 2 3 0 0 0 0 0  <br/>

Comment: The first difference in there is row zero, column one, where you expect `1`.  That is the result of multiplying `1 0 0` from row 1 of B times `0 0 1` from row 2 of A, which is correctly 0, not 1, which explains your mistake.

Comment: BTW, next time someone comments on information missing from a question you asked, please edit the original question to add the information, rather than add the information with another comment.  That applies to your answer to coincoin's question and applies even more so to your comment contrasting the output you got with the output you expected.  Those things **belong in the original question**

Comment: Write mathematic formula that you are trying to implement. What is `BZI`? If you write about inner matrix product it should be just multiplication of rows from A by columns from B.

Answer (score 0):

In both BZI and the first column of B you used one based row indexing, but C++ uses zero based row indexing.

So you need to compensate, where you had `BZI[ik]` you needed `BZI[ik]-1`

Notice also how hard it was to reach that answer without being told what output you expected (only your program wasn't working) vs. how obvious it was once told what output you expected.